How can resolve an issue related to typographical issues like using at symbol in ubuntu 24.04
How can I  use at symbol in the newly installed system (Ubuntu 24.04 version)

In the default keyboard, with the default language settings, @ is Shift 2. You could open an editor on a throwaway and file and type each key on the keyboard.

Ubuntu 24.04 (noble) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu noble and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu noble you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues, and please note the release is still in beta
